# Add rows based on a column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having issues with creating additional rows based on a column value.

If my PageCount = 3 then I would need to have 2 additional rows where PONo is repeated but the ImagePath is incremented by 1 for each new row.

I am able to get the first row but, creating the additional rows with the ImagePath incremented by 1 is where I am stuck.

**My result:**
[image]

**Expected result:**
[image]

Finished: [finished values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VO9l7.png)

Current Select statement:

```
        SELECT PO, CASE WHEN LEFT(u.Path,3)= 'M:\' THEN '\\ServerName\'+RIGHT(u.Path,LEN(u.Path)-3) ELSE u.Path END AS [Imagepath],PAGECOUNT
FROM OPENQUERY([LinkedServer],'select * from data.vw_purchasing_docs_unc') AS u INNER JOIN
OPENQUERY([LinkedServer],'select * from data.purchasing_docs') AS d ON u.docid=d.docid
WHERE (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),d.STATUS_DATE,120)=CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),120))
```

batch file:

```
   bcp "select d.DOCID,DOC_TYPE,PO,d.STATUS, CASE WHEN LEFT(Path,3)= 'M:\' THEN '\\ServerName'+RIGHT(DWPath,LEN(Path)-3) ELSE Path END AS ImagePath, STATUS_DATE,'No' AS dwimport from openquery([LinkedServer],'select * from data.vw_purchasing_docs_unc') as u INNER JOIN openquery([LinkedServer],'select * from dwdata.purchasing_docs') as d ON u.docid=d.docid WHERE (CONVERT(varchar(10),STATUS_DATE,120)=CONVERT(varchar(10),GETDATE(),120)) AND d.STATUS IN ('FILED - Processing Complete','FILED - Partial Payment','FILED - Confirming') AND DOC_TYPE IN ('CO = Change Order','Purchase Order','CP = Capital Projects','Change Order','PO = Purchase Order','PO','PR = General Operating')" queryout "E:\Data\PO Trigger CSV\PO_Trigger_Doc.csv" -r \n -T -c -t"," -Umv -Smtvwrtst -Pm -q -k
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select ponumber,b.rplc,pagecount
from table t
cross apply
(select replace(imagepath,'f'+cast(n-1) as varchar(100),'f0') as rplc from numbers n where n<=t.pagecount)b
```

To create numbers table,if you are wondering why you need it.Look [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/why-are-numbers-tables-invaluable)

```
CREATE TABLE Number (N INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL);
GO

INSERT INTO Number DEFAULT VALUES;
GO 10000
```

Using your select statement after update:

```
;With cte(ponumber,imagepath,pagecount)
as
SELECT PO, CASE WHEN LEFT(u.Path,3)= 'M:\' THEN '\\ServerName\'+RIGHT(u.Path,LEN(u.Path)-3) ELSE u.Path END AS [Imagepath],PAGECOUNT
FROM OPENQUERY([LinkedServer],'select * from data.vw_purchasing_docs_unc') AS u INNER JOIN
OPENQUERY([LinkedServer],'select * from data.purchasing_docs') AS d ON u.docid=d.docid
WHERE (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),d.STATUS_DATE,120)=CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),120))
)
select Ponumber,b.rplc,pagecount from cte c
cross apply
 (select replace(imagepath,'f'+cast((n-1) as varchar(100)),'f0') as rplc from numbers n where n<=c.pagecount)b
```

Comment: @downvoters: Pease leave a comment when you downvote

Comment: Not sure why this got a downvote but such is the nature of SO. Many people will downvote and say nothing. A numbers or tally table is the right way to do this for sure.

Comment: The tally table has been referred to as "the Swiss Army knife of sql" and it is true. It can replace loops in addition to a zillion other uses.

Comment: @TheGameiswar how about row_number partition by pono and then right of 1 ?

Comment: @developer:i am not 100% sure right now on how we can loop using that

Comment: I roll backed it no issues

Comment: @TheGameiswar  with creating the numbers table would I need to create it as a temp table? How would I set it to be the number of what PageCount is?

Comment: @jest: Create numbers table with the script i have given,it sure will be helpfull..see my updated answer using your select

Comment: @TheGameiswar the goal is to run this a batch file to create a csv file of all the PO documents for the day. Currently I have it working updated code above. then they told me that there are other documents in the same folder but they dont have a sql reference. After digging around I found that if the PageCount is great than 1 then I would have to increment the imagepath by 1 based on the number of pages where f0 = 1st page but, the PageCount is dynamic per PO Number.

Comment: when ever pagecount changes ,output also changes as per your expected result.

Comment: @TheGameiswar  with the code from above I am getting an Incorrect syntax near 'cast', expected 'AS'   the replace function requires 3 arguments

Comment: @jest:please try now

Comment: @TheGameiswar  perfect except an error on my side, I forgot that the imagepath actually has the extension .pdf and isnt working because of that. I took off the .pdf in the screen shots not thinking.

Comment: @TheGameiswar Im not sure why, but the f0 wont increment, should be if PageCount is greater than 1, it should increment by 1 starting with 0.  If PageCount = 4 then f0,pdf = page 1, f1.pdf = page 2, f2.pdf = page 3, f3.pdf = page 4

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to avoid additional table, you can use CTE:

```
WITH Images AS
(
  SELECT * FROM (VALUES
  ('C:\Folder', 2),
  ('D:\Folder', 3)) T(ImagePath, Val)
), Numbers AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4)) T(N)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT N1.N*4+T.N N FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4)) T(N) CROSS JOIN Numbers N1
    WHERE N1.N*4+T.N<=100
)
SELECT ImagePath + '\f' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10) ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ImagePath ORDER BY (SELECT 1))) NewPath
FROM Images
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP(Val) * FROM Numbers)  T(N)
```

Images is your source table. It can be anything, i.e. OPENQUERY. It produces:

```
NewPath
-------
C:\Folder\f1
C:\Folder\f2
D:\Folder\f1
D:\Folder\f2
D:\Folder\f3
```